# Show WooCommerce breadcrumbs on single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-thesis-theme

I bought a WordPress template, Zerif Pro, from Themeisle which support WooCommerce. The template WooCommerce pages don't show the breadcrumbs which allow the user to navigate from page to page. Below is the example I found online:
[image]

I searched for the function `woocommerce_breadcrumb()` in Woocommerce folder but I couldn't find the related code. Can anyone give me some tips on how do I add it on my page?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 <?php $args = array(
        'delimiter' => '/',
        'before' => '<span class="breadcrumb-title">' . __( 'This is where you are:', 'woothemes' ) . '</span>'
    );
    woocommerce_breadcrumb( $args );
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete the 3 steps in this image:

[image]